# Get List of User with Permission

Tags: mongodb

I want to create a query which basically finds out the users with their privileges i.e if a user has a role - admin then want to see what privileges have this role and to whom this role is assigned

Answer (score 0):

Use [db.getUsers()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getUsers/) command:

```
db.getUsers({ showCredentials: true })
```

Note, users are defined on a database, typically `admin`. So you would have to run

```
db.getSiblingDB("admin").getUsers({ showCredentials: true })
```

In case you need to scan all databases, you could use this one:

```
db.adminCommand({ listDatabases: 1, nameOnly: true }).databases.forEach(function (doc) {
   db.getSiblingDB(doc.name).getUsers({ showCredentials: true }).forEach(function (user) {
      printjson({ _id: user._id, user: user.user, db: user.db, roles: user.roles });
   });
});
```

The privileges of a role you can get with [db.getRoles()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getRoles/). Similar to `db.getUsers()` the roles could be defined in any database.

In general I don't see any reason to define users and roles in other database than `admin` - it makes your life much easier.